# Setup webpack for react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm new to react and webpack. I have a very simple react project and tried to load it using webpack, but it shows only `public/index.html` file. None of my components are loading.

I've added some packages like

> babel-core,babel-loader,babel-preset-es2015,babel-preset-react,css-loader,webpack

to `devDependencies`

and here is my webpack config file

```js
/*
    ./webpack.config.js
*/
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './public/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: false
})

var ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]},
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loaders: ['file-loader?context=src/images&name=images/[path][name].[ext]', {
          loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
          query: {
            mozjpeg: {
              progressive: true,
            },
            gifsicle: {
              interlaced: false,
            },
            optipng: {
              optimizationLevel: 4,
            },
            pngquant: {
              quality: '75-90',
              speed: 3,
            },
          },
        }],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: __dirname,
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    HtmlWebpackPluginConfig,
    new ManifestPlugin()
  ]
}
```

here is my `src/index.js` file

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

and here is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->

    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is my console log after start

```
yarn start
yarn run v1.2.1
$ webpack-dev-server
Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
webpack output is served from /
Hash: 8af99359537f6384fd41
Version: webpack 3.8.1
Time: 3425ms
                            Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
images/_/components/Home/back.png    24.4 kB          [emitted]
                  index_bundle.js    1.41 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
                       index.html    1.52 kB          [emitted]
                    manifest.json  114 bytes          [emitted]
   [0] ./node_modules/react/index.js 190 bytes {0} [built]
  [29] ./node_modules/react-router-dom/es/index.js 925 bytes {0} [built]
  [39] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.js 40 bytes {0} [built]
  [40] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 7.95 kB {0} [built]
  [41] ./node_modules/url/url.js 23.3 kB {0} [built]
  [48] ./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]
  [50] ./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js 7.74 kB {0} [built]
  [51] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 kB {0} [built]
  [53] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.73 kB {0} [built]
  [58] (webpack)/hot nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {0} [built]
  [60] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 75 bytes {0} [built]
  [62] ./src/index.js 723 bytes {0} [built]
  [65] ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js 1.36 kB {0} [built]
 [104] ./src/App.js 2.52 kB {0} [built]
 [117] ./src/registerServiceWorker.js 4.03 kB {0} [built]
    + 103 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
       [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./public/index.html 1.92 kB {0} [built]
       [1] ./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js 540 kB {0} [built]
       [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 488 bytes {0} [built]
       [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 495 bytes {0} [built]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: post your `html` file please

Comment: i just updated the question

Comment: you need to include your script somewhere in index.html

Comment: main.bundle.js you mean? should I manually do that ? or is there a way to include it automatically ?

Comment: I would recommend you to use "create-react-app" to avoid configuration problems https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: I created and have been maintain an updated base project you could take a look at https://github.com/geuis/webpack-react-base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are not including the script `webpack` generates for you in the `html` file.

At its most simple form, `webpack` requires an `entry`, and an `output`.

How about we look at a *simpler* example to learn how webpack works like so:

`webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
};
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Try to run `webpack` and launch your `index.html` file manually, once that goes through run `webpack-dev-server`.

Comment: i don't have dist folder. i just have build folder and main.bundle.js.

Comment: and that has GET http://localhost:8080/build/main.bunlde.js net::ERR_ABORTED error

Comment: look at what you're outputing: `output: {path: path.resolve('dist'), filename: 'index_bundle.js'}`. I'll update my answer per your request though.

Comment: I didn't have that folder so I made it and ran the project but still dist folder is empty .  and now I have http://localhost:8080/dist/index_bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have set inject to false. If you don't do that, webpack will create script tags for all the generated scripts in in output dir.

```
const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './public/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  // inject: false
})
```